# Race condition with python multiprocessing, sympy, and numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, sympy

I need to calculate numerical values for a large number of large `sympy` expressions involving matrices with `sympy.lambdify` and want to seed up the process with `multiprocessing`.

Concretely I am doing

```
monomialsLength = len(flatted_monomials)
self.monomialvector = []
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
monomials = pool.imap(partial(monomialmatrix, old=old, new=new), flatted_monomials)
for i, monom in enumerate(monomials, 1):
    lock.acquire()
    self.monomialvector.append(monom)
    sys.stdout.write("\r\x1b[K processed "+str(i)+" of "+str(monomialsLength)+" monomials in "+str(time.time()-time0)+" seconds ")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    lock.release()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

where `monomialmatrix` is a wrapper function around `sympy.lambdify`

```
def monomialmatrix(monomial, old=None, new=None):
   return np.array(sympy.lambdify(old, monomial, modules="numpy")(*new))
```

and `old` and `new` are lists of the `sympy` matrices appearing in `monomial` and the corresponding `numpy` arrays with which they are to be replaced, respectively.

The problem is that the above code seems to simply stall after a few iterations with the parallel processes consuming 100% of all CPUs (Python 2.7.6).

I suspect a race condition? This is the first time I am using `multiprocessing` so maybe I am just not using it correctly? Possibly a race condition? Any ideas?

Comment: The `for` loops runs sequentially in the main process.  Why do you need the lock around the list append and the `stdout` output?

Comment: I was unsure whether that would be necessary. So you say it is not? The same problem unfortunately appears without the lock.

Comment: I don't think that lock is necessary.  For debugging the problem, can you create a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to try to reproduce the problem?  I ran a simplified version of your code, and it worked fine.  Also: what operating system are you using?  If Windows, be sure you are aware of the guidelines shown at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows